# Magnolia 5.5.5 Custom Content Editor App (Stories) Custom CKEditor Config

Tags: javascript, magnolia

I have got the following problem:

I want to add a customConfig to the ckeditor of the RichTextBlock.
Therefore I want to overwrite the `content_editor_config.js` which is a static final in `TextBlockWidget.java`. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see two options:

- Extend the class and change the references to the new one (don't forget to compile the widgetset since it's client side code)
- Directly modify the `content_editor_config.js` file which seems to be the easier option if you want to modify all `TextBlocks`

Hope that helps,

Cheers,

Comment: Okay, sorry I guess I wrote that incorrect. Since the js-file is in magnolia-content-editor-widgetset-1.0.6 it is a compiled maven dependency thus not editable.. Would you suggest extending/decorating the widgetset?How can I do that?

Comment: I'm afraid you have to do that otherwise I don't see how it's gonna work. You have to get the content-editor project and change that js file and built it yourself and replace the jars in the bundle :( It's a bit complex since it's in the widgetset unfortunately.